# Android: ImageView background does not change

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have the following ImageView inside a ContraintLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_logo"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo" />
```

The `app_logo` is a nodpi PNG with a transparent background. I have checked it, it's transparent.

No matter which background-related property I set, I always get a white squircle behind the image. (A shape may come from the One UI, I guess.)

What am I missing? I have several ImageViews in my app, and every one of them has the background I need, except this one. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the `android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"` line? You probably shouldn't be referencing mipmaps in layout XML. And, besides, you already have `srcCompat` there pointing to another image.

Comment: can you provide us your image?

Comment: @GavinWright I have banged my head into the desk for two days. You saved my sanity. At first I wanted to use the app icon, then decided to use a more detailed one, but I don't know how that line got there, because I always use `scrCompat`. Please, post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried getting rid of the `android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"` line? You probably shouldn't be referencing mipmaps in layout XML. And, besides, you already have `srcCompat` there pointing to another image.